# How to prove that an $L^2$ function is also an $L^1$ function?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I have a function $f(t)$ defined on $[-a,a]$ that belongs to $L^2$. How do I prove that $f$ also belongs to $L^1$?
In general this fact is not true.
Is the cauchy-schwarz inequality the only way?
If a it's equal to pi this fact will change something?

Comment: You can use the Hölder's inequality to show this.

Comment: In this case is call Cauchy Schwarz  inequality?

Comment: Yes, for p=q=2.

Comment: Mathematical expressions can be used in your posts with $\LaTeX$ and [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

As a comment said, we use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\|f\|_{L^1([-a,a])}=\|f\cdot1\|_{L^1([-a,a])}\leq\|f\|_{L^2([-a,a])}\|1\|_{L^2([-a,a])}=\|f\|_{L^2([-a,a])}(2a)^{1/2}<\infty$$
by the given fact that $\|f\|_{L^2([-a,a])}<\infty$.

But perhaps a more fundamental way to prove it is [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Statements) with the function $\varphi(x)=x^2$.

Comment: the most fundamental way is to split $f$ into $f 1_{|f| < 1}$ and $f 1_{|f| \ge 1}$. Obviously $f 1_{|f| < 1} \in L^1([a,b])$ and since $|f(x)| 1_{|f(x)| > 1} \le |f(x)|^2 1_{|f(x)| > 1}$ we have $|f| 1_{|f| \ge 1} \in L^2([-a,a]) \implies|f|^2 1_{|f| \ge 1} \in L^1([-a,a])  \implies |f| 1_{|f| \ge 1} \in L^1([-a,a]) $. Overall $f = f 1_{|f| < 1} + f 1_{|f| \ge 1} \in L^1([-a,a])$.